# Display Instagram Images

Tags: php, instagram, photo, display

How can I display instagram photos on my website?
I'm trying to solve this using the Instagram's API but its not working correctly:

```
$user = file_get_contents( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$access_token" );
$user = json_decode($user, true)['data'];

$media = file_get_contents( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$access_token&count=5" );
$media = json_decode($media, true)['data'];

print_r($media);
```

Comment: what does it mean - __not correctly__?

Comment: `print_r($media);` showed you what?

Comment: What's not working? Are there any error messages, if so, please post them here. Are you trying to embed someone's entire feed or just some selected pictures?

Comment: it only print the text information but not the images
and I'm trying to embed the last 5 pictures

Comment: this is the tutorial that I was trying to follow: http://www.tokdigital.cc/desenvolver-site/api/mostrar-feed-instagram-site/#comment-840

Comment: I assume in the printed information there're paths to images which you can insert into `img` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the replies you expecting to see an image after printing `$media` which is an Array.

If you want to access the images from Instgram profile for example separately, you should be looping through the data fetched from the API  to retrieve each image separately and easily access the URL index in the array into `<img>` tag.

I have tried this code to fetch the data using curl and it works fine with me:

```
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$access_token");

    $result = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
    // Do Nothing
    }
    else {
    echo '
        <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
       ';
    }

  }
```

Comment: @AlessandraLuz glad to help